# Set-Cookie header not being sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies

I am learning how to handle cookies with node.js and express and I encountered a rather peculiar problem. My `cookie.js` file looks like this:

```
var router = require('express').Router();

router.get('/cookie/', function(req, res) {
    res.append('Set-Cookie', 'foo=bar').cookie('hi', 'hello').status(200).json([]);
});

module.exports = router;
```

The problem is that the server is not sending the `Set-Cookie` header. However, if I modify `Set-Cookie` to `Set-Cookiie` then the header is sent (albeit not as a cookie).

I also tried to use `res.cookie('hi', 'hello')` after requiring and using CookieParser in my `server.js` and no cookie header is being sent. Why is this happening? Are any other packages (I have a few other packages) interfering with my headers?

Additional Information: I have HTTP running at `:80` at HTTPS at `:443` (self-signed) and the cookie problem persists in both connections.

Comment: How did you check it?

Comment: I am using Postman to check.

Comment: Did you check with simple `curl -v http://...`?

Comment: It's my careless mistake. The cookie is actually being sent but since interceptor was not installed on Postman, I wasn't able to see it. Should've just sticked to curl.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that with `Postman` in order to catch `cookies` and `sessions` , you have to install a little add-on `Postman Interceptor` :

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-interceptor/aicmkgpgakddgnaphhhpliifpcfhicfo